# How to poll and maintain list of repositories added/deleted/token revoked in Bitbucket using the REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

My requirement is that an admin through a company portal tries to register an app with Bitbucket Cloud at which stage it will use Basic Auth to get all the list of workspaces, iterate each of them and retrieve all the repositories.

I need to maintain a record of which repositories were created/deleted/revoked access.  So my proposal is to use a database table which stores:  repo_id, repo_uuid, repo_slug, repo_url, created_on, updated_on, is_soft_delete.

I use Java and something like a ExecutorService and ForkJoinPool to continuously poll the system.  My question is with this infrastructure in place, how I can tell for sure that some repo has been added/removed/revoked access except by comparing the two lists obtained.  Is there a foolproof way to do this?

I am using Spring Boot and Java.

Note:  We did consider webhook approach, but it has serious limitations.  But I am open to suggestions.
Regards
Mahesh